# Please explain this difference in cross browser string.length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this code in Firefox v6.0.2 and IE7.  In Firefox, I select the radio button.  Then click test.  I get a string length of **10**.  In IE7, I get a string length of **9**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TestMethod() {

        var name;
        var address;
        var city;
        var state;
        var zip;

        var indexor = 0;
        $('input[name=radioBtnSet1]:checked').parent().siblings().each(function (i, cell) {
            if (indexor === 0)
                name = $(cell).text();
            else if (indexor === 1)
                address = $(cell).text();
            else if (indexor === 2)
                city = $(cell).text();
            else if (indexor === 3)
                state = $(cell).text();
            else if (indexor === 4)
                zip = $(cell).text();

            indexor++;
        });

        alert(name.length);
        alert('FACILITY NAME: ' + '|' + name + '|');
    }
</script>

<input id="runTest" onclick="javascript:TestMethod();" type="button" value="Test"/>

<table id="someTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value=" HHH VALUE" name="radioBtnSet1" /></td>
    <td style="text-align: left;"> HHH VALUE</td><td class="DisplayNone">200 SOME STREET DR</td>
    <td class="DisplayNone">CITY</td><td class="DisplayNone">TX</td>
    <td class="DisplayNone">75007-3726</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 1em;">9/30/2011</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th class="DisplayNone"></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Why?  How can I get these to be equivalent?

Comment: Do you need the space prefixing "HHH"?

Comment: You'll have to boil this down a lot more before people can usefully help you, there's a lot of unrelated cruft in the code in the question.

Comment: Yes,  spacing is a must.  If needed, can reduce later.  On the road

Comment: Well that's the problem. The browsers differ in their opinions of what to return for the text content when there's leading (and probably trailing) whitespace.

Comment: What's your DocType? It sounds like IE is trying to fix your leading space here.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: consider preparing a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) when asking JS/CSS-related questions next time and checking its behavior before posting. It's quicker for people to play with your code then.

Comment: replace leading white-space with  &nbsp; if you have to count the spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it can be seen in the comments in [this](http://api.jquery.com/text/) page, the problem is with jQuery's `text` function. In IE 7 it doesn't preserve the leading and trailing white spaces. In FF, it does. Hence the different strings and different lengths in IE 7 and FF.

If you need the whitespace, try using `&nbsp;` instead.